# Python - Filter out rows from dataframe based on match on columns from another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the 2 dataframes as below:

[image]

Based on the values of df2, if df1 rows matches ALL the conditions of df2, then remove it from df1.
Expected output:
[image]

If the column value is NULL, then consider it to match ALL the values, else regular match.

i.e. 1st row (from df2) only has product value (other columns are null), so filter should match all values of book, business and ONLY product = Forex; so "tr4" row should be matched and hence remove.

2nd row (form df2) has to match book = b2, all business (since NULL) and product = Swap, i.e. no rows matched with all this (AND) condition, and nothing removed.

I can have result inplace or new df, how can this be done?

Comment: post the data as text not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(df2)):
    for j in range(len(df1)):
        if (df2['book'][i] == "[NULL]" or df2['book'][i] == df1['book'][i] 
        and df2['business'][i] == "[NULL]" or df2['business'][i] == df1['business'][i]
        and df2['product'][i] == "[NULL]" or df2['product'][i] == df1['product'][i]):
            df1 = df1.drop(j)
df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. However, the df1 is going to be too big (100k-500k rows), so even if the df2 have 1-2 rows this will take a whole lot of time. Can this be done in pandas-way to be more faster?